# code: 'PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE',

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, next.js

I am building a simple application in Nextjs 13 and mysql. The app works fine on the local server but after deploying it on vercel I got this error in the logs. Please help.

```
    Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.  
        at s._parsePacket (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:88941)  
        at i._parsePacket (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:84013)  
        at i.write (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:78210)  
        at s.write (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:85479)  
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:53320)  
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:52429)  
        at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)  
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)  
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)  
        at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10)  
        --------------------  
        at s._enqueue (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:86847)  
        at s.handshake (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:85602)  
        at T.connect (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:54185)  
        at A.getConnection (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:62451)  
        at A.query (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/8416.js:1:64458)  
        at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/1066.js:1:309  
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)  
        at Object.executeQuery (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/1066.js:1:287)  
        at g (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/login/route.js:1:1001)  
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {  
      code: 'PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE',  
      fatal: true  
    }
```

Here is my connection file.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.LOCALHOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    connectionLimit: 100 // Set the connection limit
});

function executeQuery(query, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(query, params, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    executeQuery
};
```

I am using remote MYSQL.